# Error scale bar

Tags: qgis, scale-bar

I am working with QGIS 2.18.28, I have an Excel file with GPS coordinate of accident and I tried to generate a heat map. The problem is the unit of the map is not correct. So the scale bar generate a wrong scale bar. The projection is MTM zone 8 EPSG 32188
[image]

Comment: Is it necessary to use that version of QGIS? Can't you upgrade?

Comment: What @FranRaga said: Don't use QGIS 2.x! Please upgrade!

Comment: Hi Ghita, welcome to GIS.SE. QGIS 2.18 is a very outdated version, but a simple issue like that should still be resolvable if for some reaso you can't upgrade. More information would help, though. What are the projections of all your different layers? Have you made sure your project is set to 32188 with OTF enabled? (this was a common user error in QGIS 2.x) Could you share what settings are used for your scale bar - has the label unit multiplier been inadvertently changed? If you can upgrade though I would recommend it regardless

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I tried wih the new version 3.12.2 and the same problem with the scale bar

Comment: For all layers the same projection MTM zone 8 EPSG 32188, OTF was activated, the unit label multiplier is 1

Comment: Hello, thank you for your advises, at the beginning I was using an csv file (I filtered some data) but now I tried with the shapefile version directly from the government website, there is a little difference between data but it worked. Thanks a lot